# How to handle an insubordinate employee faction when I can't replace them?

Tags: management, politics, conflict

At my workplace we have a small faction of insubordinate employees who think they can do whatever the like and do not allow new hires in the same department to integrate into the team. The tension has escalated to the point that some of the new hires have resigned.

Even though I'm the owner of the company, I cannot discuss this with them. They are very disobedient and I suspect that one of them is also stealing product. The reason I can't fire them is that I cannot find other workers to replace them and we have a lot of orders to fulfil.

How should I handle this situation?

Comment: What would you do if that group got hit by a bus on the way to work?

Comment: @nvoigt: Good question. (Perhaps) I'll try to do force an overtime for a temporary amount of time on the other workers in order to cover our production needs (orders, deadlines etc.). But in this situation the team would understand that "we're hit by a bus" - we don't have people.

Comment: If the anarchic group gets hit by a bus, the other team members would understand and agree to do overtime, then why wouldn't they understand if you fired the whole group, which presumably nobody else likes anyway?

Comment: By allowing this dysfunctional group to continue as they are, you're sending a message to all other employees, and it's not a good one.  Get rid of them now before you start losing even more employees that have a better work ethic.  It may hurt in the short term, but the long-term effects of keeping them will be worse.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28773/discussion-on-question-by-john-thomas-how-to-handle-an-insubordinate-employee-fa).

Comment: I'll also remind everyone to remember the "Be nice' policy at Stack Exchange and to remain professional and polite :)

Comment: You can fire them.  I'm all for workers rights and usually would not suggest firing people but this sounds extreme.  What about starting with the worst and replacing them?  This might even fix the problem with the others.

Comment: If you want answers other than communication or firing, you'll have to expand on what way they are preventing new members into the team and in which way they are being disobedient so the appropriate responses can be focused on.

Comment: It would be very useful to future readers if you could write up how you choose to tackle the situation, and the eventual outcome.

Comment: You don't have to fire all of them, just start firing the worst one by one. That will then show the rest you mean business.

Comment: Did you know or ask why are they behaving this way? There is always two sides to every story.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You need to establish who is the boss, NOW.

The faction have got you by the short and curlies.  They think they are irreplaceable and are damaging your authority, possibly permanently (and stealing from you).

You need to crack down on this, make them know that they need to shape up or ship out, and mean it.  The orders to fulfill can't stop you following through on this, you have a contingency in the "hit by bus" scenario, so you can survive it (the decent staff will understand as much as the bus scenario).  By sound even bolstering your workforce with untrained people would be better.

You will find you get to a point where you cannot hire new staff (I'm sure the recent leavers will be telling people why they left), these people are a threat to your business, not just in fulfilling your current orders, but generally, deal with them NOW.

Comment: Not NOW, but LAST WEEK! That would be a more accurate time. But yes, I agree with you. The problem is finding replacements quickly.

Comment: "You need to crack down on this, make them know that they need to shape up or ship out, and mean it." and by mean it... that means follow through. Will it hurt in the short term? Yes. Will you go crazy in the long term otherwise? Yes.

Comment: This answer assumes that the view in the question is entirely correct, that the employees are entirely in the wrong. It is a very top-down view. If there are systemic management issues which have fed or created this behaviour, this approach will only increase staff turnover. It is very rare for staff issues to be black-and-white as this answer implies, and if there are good employees who have been caught up in this situation you risk raising tensions and losing the best employees first. Junior employees with talent can be the answer to the problem unless you push them out with harsh punishment

Comment: +1 Great advice. When someone's "got you by the short and curlies" it's difficult to focus on anything as it is quite painful.

Comment: @PhilH Good point; always good to step back and see the whole picture.

Comment: Chances are if you fire the worst one the rest of them will shape up.

Comment: I agree with @DeanMacGregor. You start kicking the shit out by beginning the termination procedure of the worst one. You will probably have to contend with at most 3 other in the list and the rest, either they will run away or get in shape..

Answer (score 83):

I can appreciate that you feel you can't fire them. It's a very difficult thing to do in the face of potential lost business, but as @jwsc pointed out the longer vision includes them killing this business for you eventually simply by nature of damaging your employer/employee relationship publicly.

My next bit of advice is tempered with the assumption that you've already tried communicating with each of these individuals to indicate that the behavior is not acceptable, and they've already decided to ignore this communication.

I would recommend initiating a performance improvement plan for each of them individually and privately. Have the problems you've identified bulleted out for them. Given them specific timelines and expectations. Tell them the behavior you see, the behavior you want to see and what steps you think they need to take to bridge the two.

They're likely to discuss these meetings among themselves, and if their behavior is as you describe there will be a fair bit of mocking. Endure it. Since all of their timelines and actions should be similar, when they fail to meet these expectations select the individual who seems to act as the linchpin of the group (the one around whom most of them gravitate). Terminate this individual's employment without a big show or any kind of drama. Just do it professionally and respectfully.

In most cases the "mob" will begin to look to their own interests. While they may feel solidarity with their terminated colleague it's a different matter to put their own employment on the line. Then if you don't see improvement over time, continue the process until each of them is replaced. With each individual released the group will reshape itself until finally it looks and behaves in a manner that is beneficial to the business.

On a side note, the situation has only gotten this way through some kind of lack of oversight. Either you were unable or unwilling to be "the bad guy" or you have not followed through on expectations previously. You will need to "stiffen your backbone" and be prepared to follow through on threats, demands and expectations from this point forward. They're only ignoring you because you allow it or put up with it. It doesn't have to be a draconian environment, but it should be, at the very least, respectful.

Comment: +1 for the one-by-one approach. But I wouldn't waste time with a PIP. Just do it. Take out the ring leader (not quietly)  and see if whether any of the others has the fortitude to take over. Probably not. They'll start to self-select out of the organization.

Comment: @KentAnderson: I only really recommend the PIP as a form of legal protection. As with anything, documentation ends up saving the day usually. Also, making a "show" of it has more potential of embarrassing the "sacked" individual which could create further entanglements and also galvanize the spirit of those remaining. Everyone has their own style, I just personally think the professional manner is best.

Comment: Joel, it sounds like OP can put together any documentation needed, if needed. You're right, don't make show out of it (an overt attempt at humiliation is never called for) but also don't do it so quietly that nobody knows it's happened, and why. It can be done visibly, and still be done professionally and with dignity.

Comment: @KentAnderson: Yes, that was my definition of quietly when I wrote it. I can see how that sentence would look like I'm recommending that it be hidden, which is not the case. Thanks for that insight, I'll make an edit to that.

Comment: +1 for the performance improvement plan. It's not specified in the question what country the company is in, and what kinds of contracts the employees have, but in any case, an official performance improvement plan, which the employee fails, can help in case they try to sue you. Depending on the jurisdiction it can happen that firing someone without a proven reason might result in them successfully suing you, especially if they can find any pretext to claim they were discriminated against. Especially if the group is so aggressive, it is likely they'll try to accuse you of discrimination.

Comment: While others have mentioned showing or hiding the firing, I would like to add that it is important that the survivors clearly know *why* the firing occurred.  They may be able to easily guess, but having it said, connected, out loud is certainly important.

Comment: @donjuedo: I disagree wholeheartedly. The sharing of personnel information in this fashion is inappropriate and sows discord among the "survivors". Employee X has been let go. The others who have been placed on a PIP can be left to wonder or collude why, but the fact that someone has been let go signals that action is being taken (for whatever reason) and their performance determines if that action is taken against them. Discretion with respect to employee information is always a paramount concern.

Comment: I'm with @donjuedo on this one.  Sometimes the head on the pike is entirely appropriate.  If the OP's assessment is accurate, then this is probably one of those times.

Comment: @JoelEtherton:  You bring up an important point about personnel privacy -- that boundary must be preserved, I agree.  As you say, "the fact that someone has been let to *signals* [emphasis mine] that ... their performance determines...".  That signal is what I meant to say is important to emphasize.  I should add, the change in consequences really amounts to a new set of rules, and it's only fair to spell out that there are new rules (old, unenforced rules don't count).

Comment: One consequence of firing the ring leader may be that the others all threaten to leave as well, thinking the boss surely wouldn't let them all go. That circumstance aligns with the fact that they know they are hard to replace. If that were to happen I would take the stance to be sorry to see them go but if that's what they choose then so be it.

Comment: There is a chance that the group will rebel entirely but I think that's the less likely outcome. However you should be ready to face that if it happens. Generally in these situations taking out the "ring-leader" will make the rest unhappy for a time, but they will begin to rationalize it to each other saying "Yeah he really was a jerk." Be prepared to have a *good reason* to single one of them out or they may cry foul about fairness. The less ground they have to stand on the smoother the transition will be.

Answer (score 39):

**This problem is a result of non-management. Perhaps *some* management would rectify the situation.**

Everyone else is exploring the "PIP and fire them now" side. I'm going to explore other possibilities that may allow you to avoid firings and avoid good people leaving.

> Now, perhaps you wonder why I don't fire them. We cannot find other
>   workers at the time to take their place, and we have a lot of orders
>   to fulfill.

People that are hard to replace typically require a lot of training or education to do their jobs. Unskilled laborers are easier to replace than skilled laborers.

Therefore, it sounds like you have [knowledge workers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_worker) of some type.

If you follow the harsh recommendations I'm seeing here, I think they'll be very unhappy and much more likely to leave. You could destroy your own business if they feel you've mistreated them.

> [they] do not allow newer workers hired in the same department to integrate into the team

If they *are* knowledge workers, perhaps they have good reason to keep the new guys at arm's length. It could be that they have a long-term strategy to integrate the new people and you simply aren't aware of it yet. It could be a short-sighted strategy based on pressure to deliver. It *could* be that they really aren't cooperating with your strategy of making them more easily redundant. But since your business relies on them and they are so difficult to replace, you need to take a more careful tack with them than firings and warnings.

Perhaps you could better use their self-interested reaction to pressures for your benefit and thus better align everyone's interests. Some suggestions along these lines:

- Talk to them about their strategy to integrate the new hires. Find out what their concerns are about the new people. Ask if they've created any problems. See if you can do anything to help (you probably can't, but the attempt shows that you're on the same side of the table as they are). Maybe the new people need training that the more tenured folk haven't made time for. Give them a balanced scorecard so that they can make the time to do these activities without feeling like they're sacrificing their performance goals.
- Elevate those with the most leadership potential to management, and make them responsible for getting productivity out of the new people. Management isn't for everyone, if you determine a leader you picked isn't working out, you'll want to move them back into the single contributor role while feeling that their compensation is handled fairly. You'll want to structure their compensation to separately compensate for their management responsibilities. Maybe you'll have several managers, each in charge of integrating a few people.
- Hire a manager from the outside to be solely responsible for the above strategies and for optimizing your long-term output. He'll be much easier to fire if he's not working out.

From the original question:

> The tension has escalated to the point that some of the new hires have resigned.

A commenter comments:

> This makes them (at the very best) extremely bad at managing people, and the suggestion that you promote any of the to a management position is laughable.

I think that's a simplistic view. In fact, we don't know very much about this situation. If they're knowledge workers, as I am assuming, there may well be a few of them that would make good managers. Maybe there are others at the firm that could fill that role. Maybe it's impossible, and the recommendation (one of several) is no good. But if your people leave and you can't replace them, you'll be out of business.

Another comment:

> Minimum wage jobs can be harder to fill if other unskilled positions pay more.

If what you're assuming is true, the simple solution, then, is to pay a competitive wage. 
If they can't pay competitively, then the firm's business model is built on an unsustainable strategy of only paying below-market wages.

If the firm can't afford to pay competitive wages, it's a question of its competitiveness in the industry. If it can't compete then it *should* fail.

Let's imagine, on the other hand, that this is a software development shop. Stealing from production was, for example, someone running an IRC client on a production server (which they shouldn't do, but maybe they felt entitled to as a job perk or as part of the culture, or maybe they're actually using it for business purposes). Then these are developers, and the senior developers naturally want to keep their new hires at arms length until they learn the processes and expectations of their development culture. If that's the case, here's the other side of this question: [What is a 'friendly' way to let managers know that having good developers is a privilege?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/18119/12321)

Comment: Yeah, this sure strikes me as a situation where some involved conversations trying to understand their concerns is the best first step...

Comment: This is by far my favourite answer - Give them more responsibility and encourage growth, rather than just making an example.

Comment: Did you read the part of the question where it says "new workers have quit because of the tensions". This makes them (at the very best) extremely bad at managing people, and the suggestion that you promote any of the to a management position is laughable.

Comment: Thanks, I explained my reasoning above, adding these lines: "Unskilled laborers are easy to replace. People that are hard to replace require a lot of training or education to do their jobs."

Answer (score 15):

How I would handle this situation:

I'd call that team into a meeting.  I'd list the behaviors that I saw as detrimental to the company.  Then I'd pick the worst offender and fire them right then, in front of everyone else.  After that person was walked out, I'd then resume the meeting and explain what my expectations going forward were.  I'd then put all of them on notice with a Personal Improvement Plan.

That same day I would list several open positions within the company on various job sites and attempt to hire their replacements.  Don't try to hide this - it's yet another way to let them know you are very serious.

There are several possibilities for what would happen after that.

- They shape up.  Sometimes the fear induced when you realize that your very job is on the line can help bring focus and clarity to your job.
- Some quit.  Good riddance.  Yes this would be a tough time and I've certainly lost people at critical junctures but that is just a business problem you should be able to handle.  As others have pointed out it's no different than if they were all hit by that proverbial bus.
- The don't quit and don't shape up.  Continue firing them, as you locate their replacements.  Speaking of which, the new hires should not report to the new group and you should try and separate their responsibilities as much as possible as you remove the old team.

---

Now, one last thing you should do is find out *why* they are acting this way.  Sometimes it has to do with specific company policies.  Sometimes it's simply a few people with bad attitudes.  If there is something you can change in the workplace to make their lives easier then do it.  Regardless I'd say this team is beyond redemption and you're best bet is to replace them as quickly as possible.

Comment: I like the principle, but NEVER fire someone in an open meeting. That will probably get you a walk-out, and if you are not in the USA a lawsuit.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I'm the owner; the OP is also the owner.  So being walked out as the firer is incredibly unlikely.  I agree under normal circumstances you should handle firing an employee in private; however, in this case where the entire team likely needs to be removed a little publicity would, in my opinion, help.  Further this sounds like a small company so the act, the reasons for it, etc aren't going to be private anyway.  As an alternative, fire the employee, walk them out, then have the meeting.

Comment: I'm not saying don't tell people Bill has been fired. But if you fire someone in front of people many bad things can happen. First, other employees start to feel sympathetic to them, even if they weren't before. Next, the second you fire someone in a meeting you now have a person standing there with nothing to lose. They can say and do anything they want. That's bad for you. Next you never know how someone will react to being fired. Many possibilities are bad for you.  Don't worry about people not knowing - an hour after you've fired someone in private everybody in the company will know.

Comment: This sounds like a great way to destroy your credibility as a manager/CEO.

Comment: @NotMe When I said "get you a walk-out" I didn't mean you will be walked out of the office. I mean your staff will be more likely to walk themselves out - i.e. quit en masse.

Comment: @DJClayworth: From what the OP said, that would be a good solution to the problem.  Wouldn't have to pay unemployment and he's likely going to end up firing the lot anyway.

Comment: @NotMe As (I hope), a trustworthy employee, if the owner of my company did this public ritual to a fellow employee, even the most gigantic jackass in the company, I would have my CV updated and be soliciting offers by the end of the day. If your company is willing to humiliate you based on a bad relationship, it's not your company; it's a place that offers you money for humiliation and toil.
Everything else you've laid out is setting boundaries and handling the issue. Standing them up in front of a crowd is just vicious theatre.

Comment: @deworde: To be perfectly clear, you think a thief ought to be quietly patted on the head and asked to leave in private?

Comment: @NotMe No, I think an employee should always be reprimanded and fired in private, and if you're going to refer them to the police for theft, you'd still have them wait alone in private.
Their misdemeanors can *then* be made public if necessary to stop further issues (although I personally prefer the "steps have been taken to stop this behaviour, doing this can and has led to immediate termination" rather than the "Dan was doing this, so we fired him, let's all judge Dan", if only because if Dan is proven innocent then you don't get sued for defamation and loss of earnings).

Comment: @deworde: fair enough.

Comment: This Ari Gold style management "technique" would make for a great episode of Entourage but I hope the upvoters realise how incredibly petty, vindictive and demoralising this kind of action would be.

Comment: So apart from exhibiting incredibly unprofessional and petty behavior to everyone, including the people you don't want to fire (and some short lived satisfaction) what does this achieve? If the story gets out (it will invariably), you discourage potential employees (internal strive and a manager who can't keep control of his people without public humiliation rituals? Sounds like an awesome place to work!) and business partners (Wait, I thought we were dealing with a professional?).

Comment: I've seen two rounds of 'firing' one justified, the other not, of very talented very mission critical people.  In the justified case the core group of trouble makers had been out drinking the afternoon before a scheduled release night.  They then brought more alcohol in for the release and proceeded to screw around and mess things up keeping the rest of the team hanging.  There was a complaint filed at 7:00 am the next morning by those affected.  They offending 4 some was fired by the end of the day.    We survived, it was rocky, but don't think you can't clean house.

Answer (score 14):

**Don't handle this problem yourself.**

This is not a problem that suddenly appeared overnight. Unless you're a new owner that took over this business yesterday because your Aunt Sally died last week, chances are that this is a systemic problem that slowly grew and developed itself silently under your own supervision (or lack thereof).

And chances are, you're currently missing the experience or the personality, to manage your business into its next growth phase. Please do not take this as an indictment or as a negative judgement of your intelligence or your achievements. I do not mean to say that you will lack this know-how forever, I just mean that you're currently lacking that know-how right now.

And in cases like these, I'm recommending that you start replacing yourself  (even if it's only a temporary measure), and not replace the underlings. 
Firing even one underling can be problematic, especially if they stick together, of if you perceive them as your friends, and not as your employees. As a human being, it can be suddenly very difficult to change your own behavioral patterns overnight.

So hire yourself a manager. Hire yourself a sergeant, or a line-manager, preferably someone already in the industry your business is already in. Screen that person carefully. Do not look for a double of yourself, look for someone who has the personality traits and the lower management successful track record that you do not have yourself. That person doesn't need to be as smart as you are. That person doesn't need to have gone to the same school as you have. That person just needs to have thrived in a successful highly structured environment in the same industry as yours. That person will either be a current manager, or a current assistant manager. Unfortunately, unless you're paying much more than your competitors, you're probably only going to be able to poach someone who is currently an assistant manager.

But that's ok, just do your due diligence. Make sure that person has a backbone. Then once you hire that person, a person you trust, give him or her the full authority to fire everyone if he / she has to. Not that this is the plan, it's not. Just know that this person needs to have that kind of authority, even that authority never gets exercised. Then, let go of the business and let him/her handle it. If you want to help, help, but never by second-guessing his actions. Chances are, you won't like his actions. They won't feel natural to you. But stay the course. What feels natural to you is probably what got you into this mess in the first place.

Comment: `What feels natural to you is probably what got you into this mess in the first place` right on.

Comment: Good point about not assigning all the blame to the employees - it takes two to tango, as the saying goes...

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I really ask you why you do not fire them. :)

Try to find a replacement for them immediately. If it is possible, limit their interaction with new workers to the minimum and assist your new ones as good as you can. They have to feel welcome, even if your anarchos want to push them out.

In the meantime, find out WHY they act that way. Did they have problems with the new colleagues? Are they feeling untouchable? Maybe you can help them with their problems, and everything works out fine for all of you.

If not, make it crystal clear to them that their behavior is not tolerated. Write an performance improvement plan and let them sign it. If they do not change, you will have no other choice than fire them.

Comment: "Yes, I really ask you why you do not fire them." He says he can't replace them, and won't be able to fill orders if he fires them.

Comment: It sounds like you are going to be better of without these people than with them.  You need to fire en mass with no warning and fully lock out their electronic access.  This group seems like they will sabotage your systems if you are not careful.  Then go out and hire a consulting firm that can get some boots on the ground right away.  That should give you some working room while you backfill with FTE.

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to go along with Aaron Hall here and suggest that *perhaps* this "small faction of insubordinate employees" knows (or thinks it knows, anyway) a bit more about your product and (especially) the process required to deliver it than you do.  You believe them to be indispensable.  There is a reason for your belief, right?

On the other hand, they could just be a bunch of Prima Donnas, but before firing the lot wholesale as many here suggest, and risking the continued success of your business, I would try to root out the source of the insubordination.

I'd also be as specific as possible when you approach them, individually or collectively.  That is, instead of "Why are you being insubordinate?", something more along the lines of "When I told you to do 'X', why didn't you want to do it?"

Answer (score 6):

The Wandering Dev Mana has hit the basic principles, but let me suggest some specific actions. Your first aim should be to stop this bad behaviour. In the long run letting it continue will kill the company, whether or not you fulfil the orders. After that your priority is lose as few people as possible.

1. Get each person individually into your office. Tell him the behaviour you have observed, and tell him how it is hurting the company. Ask why he is behaving like this.
2. If he raises some valid issues, agree to do your best to address them as far as possible.
3. Regardless, tell him you expect his behaviour to change. Give him specific behaviours to change, and a short timescale in which to change them. It's important that you do this individually. If you do it as a group they are more likely to try to argue with you.
4. If anyone refuses point blank to change their behaviour (hopefully unlikely if you have explained the reasoning clearly) , fire them as soon as your local employment laws allow - immediately if possible.
5. Allow a couple of days between each interview, and start with the worst offenders. This means that if you have to fire the first person, you can start your interview with the second with "I think you should know that we had to let Bill go this morning", and if not you can say "I'm having this conversation with several people, and they have all agreed with what I say", either of which should have a motivating effect.
6. Follow up with regular frequent meetings with each person and track whether each one's behaviour has actually improved. If it hasn't, fire the worst offender(s). Rinse, repeat.
7. Don't allow any of the conversations to become about what other people do - focus only on the behaviour of the person you are talking to.

Comment: "and explain to him - forcefully" How do you explain forcefully? "If you do it as a group they are more likely to stand up to you." "Stand up to" is a verb construction, the object of which is usually a bully. And the firings, in your points 2 and 4 - he says he can't replace them and can't fill orders without them, so I don't see how this works.

Comment: "Forcefully" means, instead of saying things like "I'd really like it if you did things differently", you say "The way you are acting is hurting the company, and it is necessary for you to change it." This is an entirely appropriate thing for the boss of a company to say. This approach gives you a better chance of fixing the biggest problem while still keeping most of your workers.

Comment: Don't forget to read The Wandering Dev Manager's answer in conjunction with this. He has said a lot of good things i haven't bothered to duplicate.

Comment: `"Your first aim should be to stop this bad behaviour."` I'd actually say that the first aim should be figuring out the reason for the behavior. If _an entire team of his most senior employees_ are acting a certain way, there's probably a reason and it might even be a valid one.

Answer (score 2):

Your mutinous group is acting that way because they think they're indispensable.  Today that may actually be true, at least in the short term.

Your mutiny cabal thinks that it's an "us" against "them" situation, with "them" being the rest of the company.

There is a simple and elegant solution to your problem:

1) Reassign;

2) Cross-train.

The situation you have today is that you can't afford to lose the entire group, but you CAN lose one or two.  But you don't even have to lose them.  You take the worst ring-leader of the bunch, and you REASSIGN him to a different department.  Your reason?  "WE" need to all become more adaptable in handling other aspects of the business.  This is "probably" temporary, it's a cross-training exercise.  You switch him/her with another well-respected employee from another department, and they both are SPECIFICALLY charged with cross-training each other's job.

This is "a good thing."

When you do this, the "mutiny cabal" will most certainly see what the gig is, and they'll know that you're taking away their trump card.

Your ring-leaders will object that it's not efficient or a good use of their time, and the simple answer is, "we know this will affect our efficiency over the short term, but it's a long-term vision that is about making sure ALL employees have a chance to build their skills."

After a little while, it will become apparent to the department that the company will be able to function without them, at least on a short term emergency basis.  When they need overtime work, have one of your cross-trainees from another department pick up the extra hours instead of them.

Once you're out from under their thumb, you'll find, as others have remarked, that you likely have one or possibly two "ring leaders" who are influencing the whole gang, and they will rebel, and you can let them move on to other opportunities at some other company, and the rest will look hard and long at their own personal best interests.

Comment: It sounds like this is a small business, since the OP is both the owner of the company and the boss of these employees. I don't think there are other departments that they could be reassigned to.

Comment: @DavidK, since there's not any information on company size, we're both then making untoward assumptions then, aren't we?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that they

> think they can do whatever the[y] like

From your question it seems the reason that they think this is: you allow them to do whatever they like.

As the boss you have exactly one power over them: You pay them money, which they probably need. It seems they convinced themselves that you don't have the power to take that away.

The most surefire way to convince them that they actually can lose their job is to **fire one of them**. Don't threaten them with being fired, because empty threats only make things worse.

Once you've fired one of them, they will take write ups and warnings a lot more seriously, and that is the best way to avoid having to fire the others. If you first threaten each of them, as suggested in many other answers, they are likely to call what they believe to be a bluff. If they all give you reason to fire them after the threat, yet you only fire one, this sends both  the message that you can fire them, and the message that you can only fire one of them and they are now even safer than before.

As TheJulyPlot said, you'll want to fire the ringleader, which lowers the risk of the remaining problem children organizing some form of protest.

Comment: He says he can't replace them, and won't be able to fill orders if he fires them. How do you respond to that?

Comment: @AaronHall He also says if he doesn't get them in line, new hires will resign, and that he suspects some of them are stealing. Can't have the cake and eat it too. Threatening to fire them when you and them both know you won't follow through will not resolve the situation, and neither will nice words.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is replaceable and if they are not you should work on your system and organizational chart to ensure that if some leaves you will still be able to operate.  Also, this has escalated because this type of behavior is obviously acceptable and perceived as acceptable since you keep them employed.

To deal with the insubordination I would take the following steps.

If they work on the floor then institute a 5S or cleanliness program.  Cleanliness breeds discipline and it is visible who has bought in and who hasn't.

At the next sign of subordination, pull the employee away from the group (this is important) and explain to them that this is not acceptable and this is a verbal warning.

If it happens again then give them a written warning and send them home for the day without pay.  Tell them if it happens again they're done for.  This is punitive action that is as close to firing as you can get.  At this point I would start looking for a replacement.

Next, if it happens again then it is time to dehire them.  Hopefully an example will set the others straight and if not it is not worth keeping them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You must re-assert your authority immediately. There is no need to be rude,  demanding or angry about it.

You are the boss.  It is within your authority to institute a performance-improvement plan.

After a month or two, you can schedule meetings with everyone, including the insubordinate employees.  Pick the one you will miss the least, and explain how they are being terminated.  Have a security person nearby if you really think the person may attack you.

Have your HR person escort them to their desk, observe what they are removing, and then out of the building.  Don't be angry.

This will create an example which may result in bringing the other insubordinate employees under control.  If not, you will (regrettably) have to repeat the experience. Sure, it is too bad someone has to go, but every company has a "bottom 10%" of employees, and no one expects to be employed forever anyhow.

Don't forget that you have to hire people to replace the ones you let-go.  Don't let the applicant be interviewed by the troublemakers; they will bad-mouth your company.

And meet with the group of trouble-makers and tell them you expect them to be professional and cooperate with the new employees.  And that their effectiveness in integrating the new employee is another item being tracked on their monthly performance reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to them, with a view to firing some of them.

Complying with management requests is a vital part of any job, so we are going to set up a scenario where they must either clearly comply or clearly fail. That clarity gives you the basis to fire anyone who does not comply.

You could just do that, but I think it would be better to give the team the opportunity to change direction, making it clear that you have the above process to enforce compliance. From the employee's perspective you may have been a bad manager in the past, and their clique may be a reaction to that. Unlike the trigger-happy responses here, we should allow for this possibility and create a constructive future direction.

It is unlikely that the whole team is entrenched - some are likely to be willing to change direction but caught between two polar camps. By confronting the issue directly with them individually, you make it possible for them to buy into a new option without risking the wrath of the existing team.

So the steps would then be:
1. Create a policy or edict that requires compliance, which they would usually ignore - integrating a new team member, following a new process or procedure. It must be measurable to provide clarity so that there is no wiggle room.
2. Call the team members in individually, explain what is happening, demonstrate that you are both aware of the problem and looking to resolve it constructively.
3. Follow through with the policy or change, and measure all team members comprehensively.
4. Assuming that some of the team fail to uphold the demands of the policy, fire the worst one or two, and measure for a further period. This way if there was doubt about your willingness to follow through, they have a renewed opportunity to change their path.

It is always worth considering employee issues from both sides (including the one where you are in the wrong), and I believe it is worth engaging with people and giving them the opportunity to take a good path; anything else misses the opportunity. But factions within an organisation are toxic, so the current situation must not be permitted to continue. Thus the approach here to create a fork in the road, point out the fork, and then follow through.